# Datepicker in Facebook pagetab (Page Facebook)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want Create a Booking Engine, but first, I need select dates with a Datepicker.

I Use the demo example but doesn't works, so, How I can use a Datepicker in Facebook? I can create a submit form, but, the datepicker fails.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

 <h1>TEST</h1>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean in Facebook? Do you get any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in my website I create a view for a the Page Tab and in the APP I created, I linked the view I create.